# Changing Default Size of Xfce4 Terminal

Tags: command-line, window, xfce4-terminal

How do I change the default window size of the `Xfce4` terminal emulator?
Going to `Edit` > `Preferences` on the menu does not allow me to change the window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Edit > Preferences`: See @steeldriver for explanation.

*Or*

2. On the command line, type:

   cd ~/.config/xfce4/terminal
   vi terminalrc
   Then edit the `MiscDefaultGeometry` variable to the size you would like.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the window size by changing the *default geometry* (rows x columns):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To alter the size edit the file `/usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm`.
You can use the following command `nano /usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm`

Just a few lines from the top will be the line reading:

```
:co#80:it#8:li#24:\
```

Change 80 and 24 numbers to the window size you prefer.